# Temporal: How to create a namespace programatically?

Tags: temporal-workflow

It is possible to create a namespace via the CLI, but how to do it using Java SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Programmatically it is done through [gRPC API](https://github.com/temporalio/api/blob/1b9e06b811dc75f17495e06f81a07ab7de648f2e/temporal/api/workflowservice/v1/service.proto#L48) exposed by the service.

In Java the generated gRPC client is accessible through WorkflowServiceStubs:

```
WorkflowServiceStubs service =
    WorkflowServiceStubs.newInstance(
        WorkflowServiceStubsOptions.newBuilder().setTarget(serviceAddress).build());
RegisterNamespaceRequest request =
    RegisterNamespaceRequest.newBuilder()
        .setNamespace(NAMESPACE)
        .setWorkflowExecutionRetentionPeriod(Durations.fromDays(7))
        .build();
service.blockingStub().registerNamespace(request);
```

In Go SDK you can use higher-level [NamespaceClient](https://github.com/temporalio/sdk-go/blob/00fb03096c85ee092304125c0054f2d78de377a8/client/client.go#L350):

```
client, err := client.NewNamespaceClient(client.Options{HostPort: ts.config.ServiceAddr})
    ...
err = client.Register(ctx, &workflowservice.RegisterNamespaceRequest{
    Name:                             name,
    WorkflowExecutionRetentionPeriod: &retention,
})
```

OP and additional discussion [here](https://community.temporal.io/t/creating-a-new-namespace-in-temporal/478).